# Display image in a modal window after clicking an icon on overlay

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, overlay

I have a base image in a div and when you hover over it an overlay covers it and it has a search icon in the middle. When you click on the icon I would like to load the base image in the modal window.

```
<div class="col-xs-4 column">
    <div class="overlay">   
       <i class="fa fa-search-plus im-1"></i> 
     </div>
  <img src="images/image.jpg" alt="image">
</div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
.overlay{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    left: 0px;
    right:0px;
    background-color: rgba(255,165,0,0.7);
}
/*  Displays the icon in the middle of the overlay */
.overlay .svg-inline--fa{
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    font-size:36px;
    color:#ffffff;
    width:15%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    top:40%;
}
```

And finally the JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.overlay').hide();
})


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.column').mouseenter(function(){
   $(this).find('.overlay').fadeIn('slow');
})
})

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.column').mouseleave(function(){
   $(this).find('.overlay').fadeOut('slow');
})
})
```

I have 6 of these boxes, 3 on each line, and I want to be able to click on the icon for each box and have that boxes image load in the modal window. Thanks. Edward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your html add this modal.

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="add_image">

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

In your JS.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on("click",".overlay i",function(){
    var img = $(this).parents(".column").find("img").clone();
    $("#add_image").html(img);
    $("#myModal").modal("show");
  });
});
```

Don't forget to add Bootstrap JS and CSS in your file.

Comment: Thank you so much. How cool. I did not know that you could use clone in jquery and I definitely would not have been able to put that together. I already had some code for the modal window in my global css file. I just need to tidy it all up a bit but your answer was awesome. Thanks again.